# Blank tikz preview

Tags: tikz-trees

I am having a problem with using `tikz`; I get a blank preview instead of the tree expected.  I'm using:

> Scientific Linux: v6.3     Kernel          : 2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64
>   Texlive         : TeX 3.141592 (Web2C 7.5.6)  (obtained via tex
>   --version)
>                     : pdfTeX using libpoppler 3.141592-1.40.3-2.2 (Web2C 7.5.6)  (obtained via latex --version)     Pgf             : used pgf_2.10.tds.zip, installed into a local tree, and used sudo texhash
>   gs              : 8.70     dvipdf          : apparently calls dvips
>   with the -q option     dvips           : 5.96.1

I tried the family tree and file system tree examples from http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/trees/.
  No errors or warnings occurred with `latex family-tree.tex`, for example, and `family-tree.dvi` was created (1 page, 11436 bytes).
  I can generate pdfs which don't contain `tikz` commands and view them, so it seems to me that its something peculiar to `tikz`.
I tried wrapping a

```
\begin{figure}  
\end{figure}
```

around the `tikzpicture` (using some advice seen elsewhere) but the picture remains blank.

Hope someone can help!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) It's not necessary to sign your questions (as [there is already a box with your username below it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures)) or to begin them with a greeting.

Comment: Not an answer but are you trying to create a `dvi` or a `pdf` file? If you are going for `pdf`, I am guessing `pdflatex` command would be better instead of `latex`.

Comment: @doncherry: Good hidden point! :-)

Comment: No feedback, user not seen since post of question => too localized.